# Bitmap.getPixel () processing 1D array

Tags: android, arrays, image, bitmap

My doubt is `bitmap.getPixels(allPixels, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());`
 is processing 1D array. But a bitmap is always 2D picture representation. But why there is single dimentional array?

And how the packing of bytes in 1D array?

I know this is anoob question, but I can't understand it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But a bitmap is always 2D picture representation. But why there is
>   single dimentional array?

Bitmap stored in memory as 1-dimensional array of bytes (not only bitmap, but most binary data). All pixels of the bitmap are placed in memory row by row and each row with width of bitmap. I think, method `Bitmap.getPixels()` do nothing but copy bytes from memory into `int[]` array. You are free to create your own method that will convert 1D array to 2D array, but in most cases this is not required (see below).

> And how the packing of bytes in 1D array?

Method `Bitmap.getPixels()` accepts and fills `int[]` array with length of bitmap width multiply by bitmap height. The part of result array corresponding to the rectangle, specified in parameters of the method, will be filled with colors of pixels, and rest of array will filled with zeros.

It's very easy to get the color of the desired pixel from this array. Index of pixel is `x + y * bitmapWidth`:

```
...
int width = bitmap.getWidth();
int height = bitmap.getHeight();
int[] allPixels = new int[width * height];
bitmap.getPixels(allPixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
int x = 64;
int y = 128;
int pixelColor = allPixels[x + y * width];
...
```